# Download .mp4 from Google Photo using Google Drive API will get wrong md5Checksum

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, md5, checksum

When we try to download a file with an extension of `.mp4` from Google Photo using Google Drive API, `the downloaded file always has different md5` hash value with the md5Checksum field provided by remote metadata.

For example, assume there exists a file name video.mp4 on Google Photo. After we download the file using either one of the following URL:

```
(v2) https://doc-14-6c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/[SOME_VALUES]?h=[SOME_VALUES]&e=download&gd=true

(v3) https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILEID]?alt=media
```

Both methods will download the file correctly on a local machine. The file size is also the same as the fileSize field of remote metadata.

However, the md5 hash value is inconsistent with the md5Checksum field of remote metadata. For example, if we enter $md5sum video.mp4 command, we may got `5cf9fb1bb88dc9bf38d1de5c9180dc4e video.mp4`. This is not the hash recorded at remote metadata.

All other files work fine (size and hash are consistent), except for the files with an extension of `.mp4`. By the way, we use CURL to send a request to Google Drive API to download these files, instead of using any of Google Drive SDK.

Hope someone can help us, thanks!

**[Update] more explanation**

These files are from our customer's Google Photo. We don't know the exact way to reproduce such situaion. We provide the metadata of one of problematic file for your reference. (we remove some private information.)

```
{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "(REMOVED)",
"etag": "(REMOVED)",
"selfLink": "(REMOVED)",
"webContentLink": "(REMOVED)",
"alternateLink": "(REMOVED)",
"embedLink": "(REMOVED)",
"iconLink": "(REMOVED)",
"thumbnailLink": "(REMOVED)",
"title": "(REMOVED)",
"mimeType": "video/mp4",
"description": "",
"labels": {
    "starred": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "trashed": false,
    "restricted": false,
    "viewed": false
},
"createdDate": "2016-10-10T11:42:25.000Z",
"modifiedDate": "2016-10-18T23:01:19.000Z",
"modifiedByMeDate": "2016-10-18T23:01:19.000Z",
"markedViewedByMeDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"version": "133589",
"parents": [
    {
        "kind": "drive#parentReference",
        "id": "(REMOVED)",
        "selfLink": "(REMOVED)",
        "parentLink": "(REMOVED)",
        "isRoot": false
    }
],
"downloadUrl": "(REMOVED)",
"userPermission": {
    "kind": "drive#permission",
    "etag": "(REMOVED)",
    "id": "me",
    "selfLink": "(REMOVED)",
    "role": "owner",
    "type": "user"
},
"originalFilename": "(REMOVED)",
"fileExtension": "mp4",
"md5Checksum": "c5a208198614c34b6fc61186d025df77",
"fileSize": "15284923",
"quotaBytesUsed": "0",
"ownerNames": [
    "(REMOVED)"
],
"owners": [
    {
        "kind": "drive#user",
        "displayName": "(REMOVED)",
        "picture": {
            "url": "(REMOVED)"
        },
        "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
        "permissionId": "(REMOVED)",
        "emailAddress": "(REMOVED)"
    }
],
"lastModifyingUserName": "(REMOVED)",
"lastModifyingUser": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": "(REMOVED)",
    "picture": {
        "url": "(REMOVED)"
    },
    "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
    "permissionId": "(REMOVED)",
    "emailAddress": "(REMOVED)"
},
"capabilities": {
    "canCopy": true,
    "canEdit": true
},
"editable": true,
"copyable": true,
"writersCanShare": true,
"shared": false,
"explicitlyTrashed": false,
"appDataContents": false,
"headRevisionId": "(REMOVED)",
"videoMediaMetadata": {
    "width": 720,
    "height": 1280,
    "durationMillis": "43697"
},
"spaces": [
    "photos",
    "drive"
]}
```

As you can see, the `md5Checksum` field shows `c5a208198614c34b6fc61186d025df77` in the metadata. However, the actual md5 hash value equals to `95be52d721e2f5d8d02650b27095d466` instead.

Comment: please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so that this can be tested

Comment: We don't know the exact reproducing steps, since the problematic file is from our customer's Google Photo. We provide the example file metadata instead in the problem description for your information. Thank you. @DaImTo